# FreeMarker ?has_content on Iterator

Tags: iterator, freemarker

How does FreeMarker implement `.iterator()?has_content` for Iterator ?
Does it attempt to get the first item to decide whether to render,
and does it keep it for the iteration? Or does it start another iteration?

I have found this

```
static boolean isEmpty(TemplateModel model) throws TemplateModelException
{
    if (model instanceof BeanModel) {
        ...
    } else if (model instanceof TemplateCollectionModel) {
        return !((TemplateCollectionModel) model).iterator().hasNext();
        ...
    }
}
```

But I am not sure what Freemarker wraps the `Iterator` type to.
Is it `TemplateCollectionModel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't get the first item, it just calls `hasNext()`, and yes, with the default `ObjectWrapper` (see the `object_wrapper` configuration setting) it will be treated as a `TemplateCollectionModel`, which can be listed only once though. But prior to 2.3.24 (it's unreleased when I write this), there are some glitches to look out for (see below). Also if you are using pure `BeansWrapper` instead of the default `ObjectWrapper`, there's a glitch (see below too).

Glitch (2.3.23 and earlier): If you are using the default `ObjectWrapper` (you should), and the `Iterator` is not re-get for the subsequent listing, that is, the same already wrapped value is reused, then it will freak out telling that an `Iterator` can be listed only once.

Glitch 2, with pure `BeansWrapper`: It will just always say that it has content, even if the `Iterator` is empty. That's also fixed in 2.3.24, however, you need to create the `BeansWrapper` itself (i.e., not (just) the `Configuration`) with 2.3.24 `incompatibleImprovements` for the fix to be active.

Note that `<#list ...>...<#else>...</#list>` has been and is working in all cases (even before 2.3.24).

Last not least, thanks for bringing this topic to my attention. I have fixed these in 2.3.24 because of that. (Nightly can be built from here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-freemarker/tree/2.3-gae)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! How about `<#list ...> <#items as x>` - does it also work fine with `Iterator` since introduced? Seems so, so far